# Delphi Invalid TypeCast

Tags: delphi

I am somewhat new to Delphi and development in general and really new to 64-bit development. I have the following code from a 32-bit Delphi App from XE2 that I am trying to compile in 64-bit in 10.3.3. I am getting an Invalid Typecast error and cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
procedure TSetupDialog.pPkgMethodDefaultSelected;
Var
  ParmNo: integer;
  Choice: PtrRec;
begin
  {Making sure the user selected an actual item.}
  if lbPkgDefault.Itemindex > -1 then
    begin
      Choice := PtrRec(lbPkgDefault.Items.Objects[lbPkgDefault.Itemindex]);{ read object value}<<<<Error
      { don't accept the click if item is disabled }
      if Choice.Hi = 1  then begin {item is disabled}
        messagebeep(0);
        exit;
      end;
      { put the selected parm's choiceNo = Choice.Lo in the Dealer table }
      Quote.pSetPackageUserDefault(Choice.Lo);
    end;
end;
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

```
type
  PtrRec = record  { used for typecasting Stringlist objects, i.e. pointers }
    Lo: smallInt; { 16 bits }
    Hi: smallInt; { 16 bits }
  end;
```

Comment: What is `PtrRec`? Likely it is a 32-bit value type composed of two 16-bit words, each encoding some data about the list-box item. (So you are packing two values into a single 32-bit integer.) But now the object is suddenly 64 bit, so the 32-bit `PtrRec` is of the wrong size. You could extract the parts manually (using bitwise operators), or you could extend `PtrRec` with a 32-bit dummy integer, or do something else.

Comment: PtrRec - Record describing a pointer to a memory location. But I can't find anything on how to convert this to 64-bit.

Comment: In which unit is `PtrRec` declared? It would help if you gave us the complete type definition. (Hint: Ctrl-click on `PtrRec` in the IDE.)

Comment: It is worth emphasising that the "pointer" isn't an actual pointer to a memory location in your case. You are simply using this native-size integer as a general-purpose data field (previously a 32-bit value, now a 64-bit value -- in any case, you effectively use it to store two separate values: one "is disabled" flag and one other value ("choice number"?)).

Comment: For instance, if you have `PtrRec = packed record
    Lo, Hi: Word;
  end;` you could replace it with `TItemData = packed record
    IsVisible: Word;
    ChoiceNumber: Word;
    Padding: UInt32;
  end;` This will be the correct size (word + word + UInt32 = 16 bits + 16 bits + 32 bits = 64 bits).

Comment: See [mcve]. We can't answer questions about code we can't see, and your code lacks sufficient context.

Comment: PtrRec = record  { used for typecasting Stringlist objects, i.e. pointers }
    Lo: smallInt; { 16 bits }
    Hi: smallInt; { 16 bits }

Comment: @AaronLong: We need the definition of the record! The following lines, that include `Lo`, `Hi`, all the way to the `end` which ends the record definition! We already know it is a record, we need to know its structure! :) Likely, it looks similar to my guess above.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sorry, new to this. I have edited the original post and the earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks! Then you can simply use my suggestion about `TItemData`. Or, if you prefer not to rename the type, simply add `Reserved: UInt32;` after `Lo` and `Hi`. (Well, "Reserved", "Unused", "Padding", "Dummy" -- you can choose the name freely!)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help I have fixed the issue by changing the smallInt to Integer.

Comment: @AaronLong: That is another possibility. Then both your fields will be 32-bit instead of 16-bit. If your "choice numbers" can exceed 32767, this will also fix a bug.

Comment: (And of course `Quote.pSetPackageUserDefault` must support 32-bit values. But likely it already does that.)

Comment: Doesn't really fix the problem. Now your code doesn't compile in 32 bit.